# Python: how to omit lines in a .txt file

Tags: python

I need to omit all the information before '*** START' and after '*** END' in the txt file we open in Python(so the .txt is only the body) 
We were given a string parameter and have written. it continues to write out the original .txt instead of just the body

```
def copy_file_2(s:str):
```

"that if its parameter is 'Gutenberg trim' it will copy only the body of a Project Gutenberg file, omitting the "housekeeping" material at the front and end. "

```
infile_name = input("Please enter the name of the file to copy: ")
infile = open(infile_name, 'r', errors = 'ignore')
outfile_name = input("Please enter the name of the new copy:  ")
outfile = open(outfile_name, 'w')

if s == 'Gutenberg trim':
    infile_data = infile.readlines()
    for i in range(len(infile_data)):
        t = '{:5d}: {}'.format(i+1,infile_data[i])
        if "*** START" in t:
            outfile.write(t)
else:
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line)  
infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
print re.search("START(.*)END",open("some_file").read(),re.DOTALL).groups()[0]
```

Im pretty sure should work fine for you ...

Comment: Great solution! Just in case @stormoverparis is not familiar with regular expressions, I'd add a note that the asterisks in the beginning should be escaped: `"\* START(.*)\* END` to avoid a false detection if by any chance there is one of these words in the text.

Comment: ehh unless there are alot of START and END in the file i dont think you need the asterix at all